# How can one deploy a theme to all sites within my Liferay portal?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I'm working on a Liferay portal instance that has generated some 60000 sites/communities.   These communities are already in use.  We've built up a theme for the portal,  and we're trying to deploy it to ALL communities within the portal.  We've already tested it on a few communities manually, and of course, we've already set the default theme via control panel, but there;'s got to be a smarter way to make the switchover than manually swapping 60000 sites.

Any ideas?  I'll mention:  I'm not a Liferay expert, and I don't have a lot of access to the innards of this environment, so I'm hoping the solution doesn't involve writing a new portlet or something.

Comment: You may write utility portlet which applies theme to all your 60000 site's page. You may investigate source code of `com.liferay.portlet.layoutsadmin.action.EditLayoutSetAction` and `com.liferay.portal.service.impl.LayoutSetLocalServiceImpl` and write utility

Answer (score 2):

You will definitely require to create a utility(portlet/hook) based on, when you want to apply the theme, at the time of deployment or through some button click.

You need to use LayoutSetLocalServiceUtil to perform that, if you want to apply theme to all pages of each community/sites.

Thanks,
Ankit

Comment: +1 on LayoutSetLocalServiceUtil - however, Control Panel has a Scripting Console and you can just write a Groovy or Javascript script that does the same trick. No need for a portlet/hook